# pip freeze lists uninstalled packages

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, pip

On OS X 10.6.8, I uninstalled a package using (at least pip tells me so)

```
sudo pip uninstall pkg_name
```

but the package still shows up when I do

```
pip freeze
```

I try to do the uninstall command above again, and pip tells me the package is not installed.

What is the problem here? How do I verify whether the package is uninstalled or not? If so, can I refresh some sort of index of pip to get it corrected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought you may have two `pip` binaries, and when you run as `sudo`, your shell chooses the wrong one, at first. But it does not make any sense if you run it again as `sudo` and `pip` removed the package. Did you do exactly this?

If you did not run the **same** commands twice, you may have different `pip` binaries running the uninstall and freeze. Check if the following two commands result in the same output:

```
$ sudo pip freeze
# ... sudo output
$ pip freeze
# ... normal output
```

Anyway, you can check if the package is installed using:

```
$ python -c 'import pkg_name' &> /dev/null && echo installed || echo not installed
```

There is no sort of refresh feature in `pip`.

Comment: I ran the `pip freeze` with `sudo` and without, and the results are indeed different, three packages extra without `sudo`. Also, the output of `yolk -l` shows that I have two versions of `pip` installed with the older version marked as **inactive**, is this related to the different outputs from `pip freeze`? If so, how should I correct this situation? Thanks!

Comment: It is not related to the `pip freeze` output as I know. You are just using two different `pip` binaries. You can use absolute paths to desambiguate: /path/to/bin/pip freeze. Use `which pip` and `sudo which pip` to find where your `pip`s are located.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and it was due to broken symlinks from homebrew once the file was uninstalled.

```
$ pip freeze | grep Magic
Magic-file-extensions==0.2

$ pip uninstall Magic-file-extensions
# say `y` at prompt / see it go through as success

$ pip freeze | grep Magic # still there :(
Magic-file-extensions==0.2

$ ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ | grep Magic # symlink shows up red
├── [lrwxr-xr-x tomfuert   98 Feb 16 11:06]  Magic_file_extensions-0.2-py2.7.egg-info -> ../../../Cellar/libmagic/5.17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Magic_file_extensions-0.2-py2.7.egg-info

$ rm /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Magic_file_extensions-0.2-py2.7.egg-info

$ pip freeze | grep Magic
# nothing!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a virtual environment, try clean command. Don't forget sudo.

```
sudo pipenv clean
```

Comment: This also works without a virtual environment. Remember to `pip install pipenv` first.