# pip is not uninstalling packages

Tags: shell, python-2.7, pip

**Background**

I'm working on an academic project to (basically) analyze some "who follows whom" graphs and wanted to get some real data (by building some small datasets) from Twitter using one of the Python Twitter API packages in order to test some ideas I have.

I was a bit careless and installed two packages:

a) `python-twitter0.8.2` (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/0.8.2)

b) `twitter1.9.1` (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/1.9.1)

(a) is called `python-twitter` in pypi, and (b) is called `twitter`, so that's how I'll refer to them.

Both of these are called by `import twitter` in the Python interpreter, but when I write that line, I always get the `twitter` one (if I can figure out how to use the `python-twitter` one, I'll be able to proceed, but will still have the same underlying problem).

---

**Problem**

Since I don't need the `twitter` package, I decided to uninstall it with pip:

`$ sudo pip uninstall twitter`

which gives the output:

```
Uninstalling twitter:
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled twitter
```

(actually, I tried the same thing with `python-twitter` and got a similar response).

However, when running `pip freeze`, both of these packages show up on the installed list! In fact, I can still use the `import twitter` command successfully in the interpreter. Clearly the packages have not been uninstalled. What I would love to know is how to uninstall them!

---

**Other Info**

I'm using Python 2.7 and Ubuntu 12.04

When running IDLE instead of the shell interpreter, and I type `help('modules')`, neither `twitter` nor `python-twitter` shows up in the list. When typing `help('modules')` into the shell interpreter, I get a segmentation fault error, and the interpreter crashes. Here's the error:

```
>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning:
  g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning:
  g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  from gtk import _gtk

** (python:2484): CRITICAL **: pyg_register_boxed: assertion `boxed_type != 0' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: cannot register
existing type `GdkDevice'
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: 
assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

**Why other questions have not resolved this for me:**

I looked at the similar post at [pip freeze lists uninstalled packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640530/pip-freeze-lists-uninstalled-packages) and am not having the same issues.

```
$ sudo which pip
/usr/bin/pip
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

which is the same output. In addition, `$ sudo pip freeze` gives the same output as `$ pip freeze`.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What does `import twitter; print twitter.__file__` say?

Comment: `>>> print twitter.__file__` yields: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter/__init__.pyc`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can always manually delete the packages; you can run:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter
```

to remove that package from your `dist-packages` directory. You may have to edit the `easy-install.pth` file in the same directory and remove the `twitter` entry from it.

Comment: Thanks! Should I also remove `twitter-1.9.1-py2.7.egg-info`, `twitter.py`, and `twitter.pyc` or is removing the directory enough?

Comment: Yes, remove all of those; and the `python-twitter` egg info if it is there. Remove both `twitter` and `python-twitter` from the `easy-install.pth` file (grep for the names in any other `.pth` file if there are any).

Comment: @DavidBodow: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Yes; thank you. Still curious as to what went wrong with pip, but the problem is fixed now.

Comment: Yeah. This just happened to me. Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: @BrettWidmeier, the cause of the problem is some modifications done in the debian version of pip which is also the source for the ubuntu package. See my answer below.

Comment: Note that some packages on the Raspberry Pi are /usr/lib/python<x> and not /usr/local/lib/python<x>

Comment: @DannyStaple: the location of your Python will vary on exactly how you installed Python and your distribution. Use `python -m site` to have Python tell you where it looks for packages (look for the `site-packages` entry in the `sys.path` list).

Answer (score 15):

While Martin's solution works, as a work around, it does not provide a direct answer. 
Ubuntu's pip version for your Ubuntu version (12.04) is:

```
 python-pip (1.0-1build1)
```

This is also the same version for Debian Wheezy. This version has a weired bug, which causes packages not to be removed.
If you obtain pip from upstream using the script `get-pip.py` you will have a fixed version of pip which can remove pacakges (as of now v. 1.5.6).

## update

Python's pip is really a fast moving target. So using Debian's or Ubuntu's pip is guaranteed to have bugs.  *Please* don't use those distribution's `pip`. 
Instead install pip from upstream.

If you would like to register pip installed packages as system packages I really recommend that you also use [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb).

Comment: you can get `get-pip.py` here: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: A couple of links for a deeper insight of this never-ending (at least, until Ubuntu 14.10) story: [Debian bug report log](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=751827) and [bug confirmed for Ubuntu Utopic (14.10)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1392288) (confirmed also by my personal experience).

Answer (score 4):

I was facing difficulty while upgrading a package because pip was not able to uninstall it successfully. I had to delete the .egg-info and the folder as well in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and then I tried to install with --upgrade and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was due to the fact that I was running `pip freeze`, which gave me different results than `sudo pip freeze`.

Since I was uninstalling using `sudo`, it was not uninstalling it in the "non-`sudo`" session. Uninstalling without `sudo` fixed that.

Comment: While this did not directly solve my issue, it did remind me that `pip3 install` is not necessarily equivalent to `sudo pip3 install`, which indirectly helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (moving pyusb 0.4x to 1.0x), removing the old package with apt-get remove python-usb and manually installing the manually downloaded package via python setup.py worked. Not pretty, but working.