# How to fix pip hanging on uninstalling sqlalchjemy

Tags: python, windows, sqlalchemy, pip, uninstallation

In Python 2.7.11 under Windows I have installed sqlalchemy into a virtual environment. Now, when I try to uninstall it via

```
pip uninstall sqlalchemy
```

`pip` hangs when listing the following lines:

```
.
.
.
c:\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py
c:\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.pyc
c:\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\queue.py
c:\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\queue.pyc
c:\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\topological.py
c:\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\topological.pyc
```

This happens repeatedly, when I cancel the uninstall command and issue it again, even after system restart.

What can I do to make `pip` continue?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pip?

Comment: @Yegers Yes, 8.1.2.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like pip uninstall prompts you with "Do you want to continue (Y/N)?", but that is not visible in cygwin or git bash for some reason.

Typing "y" and pressing enter makes the pip uninstall proceed.

Comment: Sounds like a great explanation! Will test it next time I come across this issue on uninstall on Windows.

Comment: Checked on uninstalling ansible via pip. It really works, thanks :)

Comment: i was able to confirm that this fixed it, it is after pressing the 'y' that the prompt "Do you want to continue (Y/N)?" appears, im using git bash

Comment: Well done for understanding this, do you know how to fix the environment of git bash to show these prints?

Comment: In Git Bash you can prefix the command with 'winpty ' to make the prompt show up properly.

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to type "y" (or you want to run it in a script), use

`pip uninstall sqlalchemy --yes`

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day, Bro. I hope this should be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: When trying this in jupyter, this is the solution (that worked for me).  Otherwise it hung

Comment: It worked for me in Azure Pipeline and saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve *why* pip hung on uninstall; however through another [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14572899) I realised that I can remove the package manually with:

```
del C:\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy
del C:\venv\Lib\site-packages\SQLAlchemy-1.0.14.dist-info
```

I checked for mentions of sqlalchemy in any *.pth file too, but there were no occurrences.

In any case, `pip freeze` revealed that the package was properly gone.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all steps but finally this works for me:

```
pip install --ignore-installed ${PACKAGE_NAME}
```