# I cannot find cv2.ximgproc after installing opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use some function of ximgproc, so I uninstalled opencv-python and re-installed opencv-contrib-python

```
(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps>pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python opencv-python
Skipping opencv-contrib-python as it is not installed.
Uninstalling opencv-python-4.5.1.48:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\cv2\*
    c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages\opencv_python-4.5.1.48.dist-info\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled opencv-python-4.5.1.48

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\eps>pip install opencv-contrib-python
Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/07/4da5e3a2262c033bd10d7f6275b6fb6c77396b2058cedd02e61dbcc4a56d/opencv_contrib_python-4.5.1.48-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\administrator\pycharmprojects\eps\venv\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.18.2)
Installing collected packages: opencv-contrib-python
Successfully installed opencv-contrib-python-4.5.1.48
```

However, I could not import ximgproc still. Is there anything I forgot ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check which packages you have intalled with `pip list`?
Even though you uninstalled opencv-python, you also need to uninstall `opencv-python-headless, opencv-contrib-python-headless` packages. As @skvark says

> never install both package

Comment: oauthlib                 3.1.0
open3d                   0.10.0.1
opencv-contrib-python    4.5.1.48
opencv-python            4.5.1.48
opt-einsum               3.2.0
packaging                20.4
pandocfilters            1.4.2

Comment: I cropped O part and will try to install contrib only

Comment: It's weird you couldn't uninstall even though you have done it before. Try again to uninstall `opencv-python 4.5.1.48` , otherwise you can try to delete manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14572899/14950238

Answer (score -1):

Install opencv and opencv-contrib modules separately.
Command for standard desktop environment:

```
$ pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: You should never install both packages. Only the latter will be actually installed and it overwrites the first one. It also makes your environment inconsistent since `pip` will show that `opencv-python` is installed but in reality it has been overwritten by `opencv-contrib-python`.