# where does `pip freeze` read info from?

Tags: python, pip

my pip version is 19.2.3, should not matter though.

I have some packages installed (maybe by pip install -e), now I have no way to undo it. I have tried clean the entry in easy-install.pth, and run `pip uninstall mypackage`, but when I run:

```
  pip freeze |grep my_package
```

it always there.

And also I have tried `make clean` to clear all eggs/tox env from my development env too.

I'm wondering where doest pip read the info from?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--user` flag to the pip uninstall?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640530/pip-freeze-lists-uninstalled-packages

Answer (score 1):

The pip `freeze` command checks your `site-packages` folder to determine what is or is not installed. The location of this folder will vary depending on a number of factors, including Python version, OS, if you are using a virtual environment, etc. My user install folder on Windows 10, for example, is `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages`

I'm not 100% sure exactly how the process works, but this can be easily verified by running `pip freeze`, then moving one of your packages out of the `site-packages` folder and running it again. You will see the package disappear from the list.

The easiest way that I'm aware of to check which folder is being used is to `pip show` a package that you have installed, e.g., `pip show websockets`. This will show you the location of the `site-packages` folder.